# Make d3.pack use more width

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3.pack because I'm using bubble chart. However, I'm using it as a wordcloud. How can I make this use more of the width and don't make it that tall?

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y422f58q/1/)

In the code I have `width: 600px; height: 1500px;` on the `#cloud` element. This makes it kind of clumsy.

Otherwise, how can I make it so they never overlap each other? That could be an issue when making the screen smaller.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi.. did you mange to solve it

Comment: Hello there! Unfortunately not. We made it manually instead, with html and CSS